# Eclipse RCP OSGi Conflict org.mortbay.jetty

Tags: eclipse-rcp, osgi, osgi-bundle

When starting my Eclipse RCP application, I experience the following error:

!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_2.0.0.v20090520-1800 [154] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2013-01-21 17:31:55.618
!MESSAGE Package uses conflict: Import-Package: org.mortbay.jetty; version="[6.1.0,7.0.0)"

This leads to the problem, that within the RCP application, the help system cannot be started (due to a ClassNotFoundException).

As far as I understand it, there is some problem with the bundle org.mortbay.jetty in the sense that it is present in a wrong version, or multiple incorrect versions. So I started my Eclipse RCP application with the program argument -console in order to get an OSGi console.

I type

```
osgi> packages org.mortbay.jetty
```

to find out about all imports and exports of this package. Which gives me the following result:

```
org.mortbay.jetty; version="6.1.15"<org.mortbay.jetty.server_6.1.15.v200905151201 [491]>
```

But this seems okay to me. Obviously, org.mortbay.jetty is exported by org.mortbay.jetty.server and it's exported version is  6.1.15, which is in the range of [6.1.0,7.0.0). Furthermore, when my colleagues try to start the application, they encounter no problem whatsover.

I also tried to use a fresh workspace for the RCP application but that didn't help as well ... I'm really clueless now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed, within the launch configuration some important plug-ins were not checked to be launched. In fact, I needed to switch from a feature-based configuration to a plug-in-based configuration.

See: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/631827/

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem some time back with jetty.

solution:

1) if u r using plug-in based eclipse rcp application  ->  remove the plugin version (major/ major)
or

2) if you are using feature based rcp application --> make sure set match="compatible"

Comment: Well, I cannot really do that. I myself am not using jetty. It's the eclipse help org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_2.0.0.v20090520-1800 that has a dependency to jetty. And I cannot change the dependencies inside the eclipse bundle.